# DISTINCT values for one column, however I also need the rest of the data associated with it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So all data is in one table i need to be able to get the main column and all its associated in a list, it will be better to give an example

```
Course....    | Subject...... |  
Maths...... . |  division.....|   
Maths.......  |  bidmass......|    
PE............| Gym work......|
```

So what i want it to return is:

```
**Maths**

Division


Bidmass

**PE**

Gym Work
```

So basically i want the course to be its title and any row associated with it  at the momment i Have:

```
SELECT Course, CONCAT(Course, ' ', Subject) AS ColumnZ 
FROM products
GROUP BY Subject
ORDER BY COurse ASC"
```

the group by Subject was used as there duplicates of subjects

How do I grab all the courses with a list of subjects so i can output this in a UL format

Comment: Okay, and what is the question?

Comment: So this is a basic loop in PHP, acting upon an ordered array. See any tutorial ever written on using PHP and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

don't group by subject, what if the same subject was in a different course, you would lose one. group by Course, then Subject like this.

```
SELECT Course, Subject, CONCAT(Course, ' ', Subject) AS ColumnZ 
FROM products
GROUP BY Course, Subject
ORDER BY Course, Subject
```

now loop through the results, put course into a variable $prev_course, and if the $row[course] changes from the previous course then you know to output the next course header $row[Course]  otherwise just output the $row[Subject]